# Filter across a range of columns in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file that contains p-values, and am looking to filter it if a p-value <=0.05 is seen in at least one column in each row, and if it is not to delete that row.

A simplified version of the file looks like (but in reality there are 30,000 rows and 327 columns):

```
gene,speciesA,speciesB,speciesC         
X,0.05,0.9, 2.6426944282e-05                      
Y,1,0.6,0.006             
Z,1,1,1
```

so i.e. if gene X has a significant value in at least one species, keep that gene. If it doesn't delete that gene.

I wrote a perl script but I don't know how to get it preform the filter across all the rows in a more logical way than writing each column out.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $file, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "$!";
my ($line);
$line = (<$file>);
print $line;    #keep the header
while ( $line = <$file> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my @ranges = split( ",", $line );
    print join( "\t", @ranges ), "\n"
        if ( $ranges[1] <= 0.05 );    #need to filter for 327 columns and ignore column[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you ask.

Note that I am reading from the `DATA` file handle for testing. If you want to read from a file with a hard-coded name then write

```
open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;
```

instead of `my $fh = \*DATA`. Or, of you want to read from a file named on the command line, then replace `<$fh>` with `<>`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'any';

my $fh = \*DATA;

print scalar <$fh>;  # Copy header

while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split /,/;
   shift @fields;
   print "$_\n" if any { $_ <= 0.05 } @fields;
}

__DATA__
gene,speciesA,speciesB,speciesC         
X,0.05,0.9,2.6426944282e-05                      
Y,1,0.6,0.006             
Z,1,1,1
```

**output**

```
gene,speciesA,speciesB,speciesC         
X,0.05,0.9,2.6426944282e-05                      
Y,1,0.6,0.006
```

Comment: I have the error message- "any" is not exported by the List::Util module- I'm using Perl/5.16.3-goolf-1.4.10. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to update your copy of `List::Util`

Comment: also it is having trouble that the first column is non numeric (the genes)

Comment: @user3816990: it removes the first column before checking

Comment: ah yes, OK it worked after I updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -F, -lane 'print if $. == 1 || ! grep {$_ <= 0.05} @F[1..$#F]' file.csv
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-F`: `split()` pattern for `-a` switch
- `-l`: Enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `$. == 1`: Checks if the current line is line number 1.
- `! grep {$_ <= 0.05} @F[1..$#F]`: Ensures no values are equal to or below 0.05

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a CSV file. An alternative maybe the DBI usage with [DBD::CSV driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, {
    f_ext      => "./csv",
    RaiseError => 1,
    }) or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

# Selecting
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("select * from foo where the_column_name<0.05");
$sth->execute;
while( my $hr = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    #...
}
```

Comment: Cheers, could you explain how the selecting part works?